# Recursive Print Method

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to print following pattern:

```
0
11
0
222
0
3333
0
222
0
11
0
```

I want to achieve this by using recursion and a loop inside said recursive method, which gets one integer value passed. The int value determines how far this pyramid pattern goes. In the example above the int value would be 3.
I managed to get the bottom half, but I have no idea to get the upper half.

```
if (arg != 0) {
            System.out.println("0");
            for (int i = 0; i <= arg; i++) {
                System.out.print(arg);
            }
            System.out.println();
            print(arg - 1);
        }
```

How would I be able to somehow implement some increment, which turns to a decrement to this recursion? Since I'm thinking this would be how I could achieve the above pattern.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for a recursive solution, or an iterative solution?

Comment: If you pass two values (1,n) and recurse up to n and then use another method to recurse down when you come up to the value of n you could.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I guess it's kind of a mix, hence the confusion. The zeros and the next numbers are supposed to be printed recursive but the numbers (1, 2, 3) are supposed to be printed through a loop (so iterative).

Comment: @arundeepchohan This can be made to work with one method and passing one value only supposedly.

Comment: `I guess it's kind of a mix` ... the problem here is that you _guess_.  Recursive and iterative solutions are very different ways of solving this, and you should be asking for only one approach, most likely.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass two arguments. The Max value and start value which will be zero and

then increment start value until reaches max

then decrement Max  until reaches zero

**call**--> `printline(3);`

```
  private static void printline(int input,  int... vars) {
        if (input == 0) {
            System.out.println(0);
            return;
        }
        int start= vars.length > 0 ? vars[0] : 0;
        start++;
        System.out.println("0");
        for (int i = 0; (i <= start && i <= input); i++) {
            System.out.print(start >= input ? input : start);
        }
        System.out.println();
        if (start >= input) {
            input--;
        }

        printline(input, start);

    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, thank you. But it is supposed to work with passing only one argument. Kind of a head scratcher to me.

Comment: make second as default argument as you will always pass zero. so when you call you will pass only one argument. updated the answer